# Straight, but not necessarily Horz or Vert, line in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, line

I would like to know the easiest way to draw a straight line between 2 divs not necessarily, horz and vert. (Think UML). There are jQuery plugins and HTML5 Canvas. It looks like the canvas would have to be the entire screen for my project, but I'd like to just use bordered divs for my boxes.The jquery plugins don't seem to be more than SVG wrappers and very experimental.

Any better ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVG would be an easy way to draw a line between two divs.

Here is a fiddle that uses raphelJS to do it:

http://jsfiddle.net/thebeebs/pgSnY/